# how to update function in .mdx file react

Tags: reactjs

I am working with react and creating .mdx file for each component. I am using a function as a props like `onSelectChange: propTypes.func`. I need this record in `.mdx` file so how can I update this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found its solution, it can be done like below

```
onSelectChange={() => yourFunction(val)}
```